# Java hash table

Tags: java

One of my assignment is to implement my own version of the hash table. I have nearly completed the
   assignment except one test keeps failing. Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

/**
 * Resize the hashtable, to be used when the load factor exceeds maxLoad. The new size of
 * the underlying array should be the smallest prime number which is at least twice the size
 * of the old array.
 */
private void resize() {
    if(getLoadFactor() >= maxLoad){
        itemCount = 0;
        int newCapacity = nextPrime(max * 2+1);
        int i = 0;

        Collection<String> c = getKeys();
        arr = new Pair[newCapacity];

        for (String key : c)
        {   int hashKey = hash(key) % newCapacity;
             V v = get(key);
            if(arr[hashKey] == null){
                arr[hashKey] = new Pair<V>(key,v);
                  itemCount++;
            }else{
                int position =  findEmpty(i, i, key);
                arr[position] = new Pair<V>(key,v);
                  itemCount++;
            }
        }



        max = newCapacity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you *expect* null? I suspect your assertion is the wrong way round to start with. After that, please tell us what you've done to diagnose the problem so far. Why are you even reimplementing a hash table yourself at all?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Also, what is the test supposed to test, in words?

Comment: Like I said it's for an assignment. I have been given this test to check it is functioning correctly. It gets to assertEquals and instantly fails. The expected null is just the response the test gives out after failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should review your resize() method.

```
// you keep all keys
Collection<String> c = getKeys(); 
// you create a new array of Pairs for the new capacity but you lose at the same time all previous values
arr = new Pair[newCapacity];
```